# Check condition if image available in upload folder or not, in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using carrier wave to upload images in rails3, 
i want to just check the condition is image available in upload folder or not.

Because in my case suppose image name available in data base but by mistake image deleted from upload folder in that scenario when click on image link getting error .

Answer (score 0):

I think, this can be done using `exist?(file_name)` method of Ruby File Class. I assume you can get the full path of the file from the database, and pass it to the class method as follows:

```
File.exist?('full/path/of/the/file')
```

This will return true if the file exists otherwise false. for reference you can read about File operations [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html)

Answer (score 0):

Carrierwave has a built-in method to do just that. It works whether your storage method is :file or :fog. Looks like this:

```
picture.data.file.exists?
```